# can someone show me a simple sample of vb.net adding customer to quickbooks

Tags: wpf, vb.net, sample, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to write a VB.net WPF program, that will add custom notes to a customer. Intuit has me going in circles with their code examples, that won't convert from C# to VB.net.

Can someone show me a very simple sample that shows adding a customers name only? Leave out any error checking etc, I can figure that out. I just don't know how to write the connection to quickbooks and send the request. Maybe a simple form with a textbox and a button, with the functionality to put the name in the textbox, and click the button to add the customer name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have long been disgusted at the poor code samples from Intuit for Quickbooks SDK. Having said that, I still use them; after fixing the code they are quite useful.

You also need to add a reference to Intuit Quickbooks SDK QBFC7Lib; It might look slightly different depending on the version.

Here is what you need to do to make the code useful (use Edit > Quick Replace):

1. Replace `//` with `'` (comments)
2. Remove all `;` (semi-colons)
3. Replace `==` with `=`
4. Replace `For j = 0` with `For j as Integer = 0`
5. Replace `responseList.GetAt(i)` with `responseList.GetAt(j)`
6. Remove trailing `.` (dot)
7. Replace `Integerfor` with `Integer` (next line) `for`
8. Replace `DataExtRet` with `DataExtRet.` (only when it shows an error)
9. Check for any other errors
10. Delete stuff you don't need

When you run it for the first time you need to have Quickbooks open and be ready to give permissions from Quickbooks. Here is a sample with the errors fixed.

```
Imports QBFC7Lib

Module QBSample

Public Class Customer

    Public Sub DoCustomerAdd()
        Dim sessionBegun As Boolean
        sessionBegun = False
        Dim connectionOpen As Boolean
        connectionOpen = False
        Dim sessionManager As QBSessionManager
        sessionManager = Nothing

        Try

            'Create the session Manager object
            sessionManager = New QBSessionManager

            'Create the message set request object to hold our request
            Dim requestMsgSet As IMsgSetRequest
            requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 7, 0)
            requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue

            BuildCustomerAddRq(requestMsgSet)

            'Connect to QuickBooks and begin a session
            sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "Your application")
            connectionOpen = True
            sessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare)
            sessionBegun = True

            'Send the request and get the response from QuickBooks
            Dim responseMsgSet As IMsgSetResponse
            responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet)

            'End the session and close the connection to QuickBooks
            sessionManager.EndSession()
            sessionBegun = False
            sessionManager.CloseConnection()
            connectionOpen = False

            WalkCustomerAddRs(responseMsgSet)
        Catch e As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error")
            If (sessionBegun) Then
                sessionManager.EndSession()
            End If
            If (connectionOpen) Then
                sessionManager.CloseConnection()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub BuildCustomerAddRq(ByVal requestMsgSet As IMsgSetRequest)
        Dim CustomerAddRq As ICustomerAdd
        CustomerAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomerAddRq()
        'Set field value for Name
        CustomerAddRq.Name.SetValue("Test Customer 2")
        'Set field value for IsActive
        CustomerAddRq.IsActive.SetValue(True)
        'Set field value for CompanyName
        CustomerAddRq.CompanyName.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Salutation
        CustomerAddRq.Salutation.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for FirstName
        CustomerAddRq.FirstName.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for MiddleName
        CustomerAddRq.MiddleName.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for LastName
        CustomerAddRq.LastName.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Addr1
        CustomerAddRq.BillAddress.Addr1.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Addr2
        CustomerAddRq.BillAddress.Addr2.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Addr3
        CustomerAddRq.BillAddress.Addr3.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Addr4
        CustomerAddRq.BillAddress.Addr4.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Phone
        CustomerAddRq.Phone.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for AltPhone
        CustomerAddRq.AltPhone.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Fax
        CustomerAddRq.Fax.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Email
        CustomerAddRq.Email.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for Contact
        CustomerAddRq.Contact.SetValue("ab")
        'Set field value for AltContact
        CustomerAddRq.AltContact.SetValue("ab")

        'May create more than one of these if needed
        CustomerAddRq.IncludeRetElementList.Add("Name")
        CustomerAddRq.IncludeRetElementList.Add("ListID")

    End Sub

    Private Sub WalkCustomerAddRs(ByVal responseMsgSet As IMsgSetResponse)
        If (responseMsgSet Is Nothing) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim responseList As IResponseList
        responseList = responseMsgSet.ResponseList
        If (responseList Is Nothing) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'if we sent only one request, there is only one response, we'll walk the list for this sample
        For j As Integer = 0 To responseList.Count - 1
            Dim response As IResponse
            response = responseList.GetAt(j)
            'check the status code of the response, 0=ok, >0 is warning
            If (response.StatusCode >= 0) Then
                'the request-specific response is in the details, make sure we have some
                If (Not response.Detail Is Nothing) Then
                    'make sure the response is the type we're expecting
                    Dim responseType As ENResponseType
                    responseType = CType(response.Type.GetValue(), ENResponseType)
                    If (responseType = ENResponseType.rtCustomerAddRs) Then
                        ''upcast to more specific type here, this is safe because we checked with response.Type check above
                        Dim CustomerRet As ICustomerRet
                        CustomerRet = CType(response.Detail, ICustomerRet)
                        WalkCustomerRet(CustomerRet)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End Sub

    Private Sub WalkCustomerRet(ByVal CustomerRet As ICustomerRet)
        If (CustomerRet Is Nothing) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Go through all the elements of ICustomerRet
        'Get value of ListID
        Dim ListID1 As String
        ListID1 = CustomerRet.ListID.GetValue()
        'Get value of Name
        Dim Name5 As String
        Name5 = CustomerRet.Name.GetValue()

    End Sub

End Class

End Module
```

Another problem I often see is the code jumping from a "retlist" to a "ret". This usually happens with queries e.g. ReceivePaymentQuery. It is not a problem with DoCustomerAdd. I only mention it here for reference when you are converting other methods.

The code from OSR:

```
Public Sub WalkReceivePaymentRet(ByVal ReceivePaymentRet As IReceivePaymentRetList)
    If (ReceivePaymentRet Is Nothing) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Fix it like this:

```
Public Sub WalkReceivePaymentRet(ByVal ReceivePaymentRetList As IReceivePaymentRetList)

    For a As Integer = 0 To ReceivePaymentRetList.Count - 1
        Dim ReceivePaymentRet As IReceivePaymentRet

        ReceivePaymentRet = ReceivePaymentRetList.GetAt(a)

        If (ReceivePaymentRet Is Nothing) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Comment: Now if Intuit could just add the corrected code to their samples, that would be great.

Comment: Here is the link to Intuit's online reference SDK for Quickbooks: https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add "AddCu" into the Quickbooks by doing the following:

QB-> Edit -> Preferences-> Integrated Applications-> Company Preferences

Allow Access: ✓   |   Application Name: AddCu

Imports Interop.QBFC13

```
Public Sub AddCu()
    ' Create a QBSessionManager object:
    Dim SessionManager As QBSessionManager
    SessionManager = New QBSessionManager

    ' Create an IMsgSetRequest object (the parameters specify US QuickBooks and the 6.0 spec):
    Dim CustomerSet As IMsgSetRequest
    CustomerSet = SessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 6, 0)

    ' Create an ICustomerAdd object:
    Dim customer As ICustomerAdd

    customer = CustomerSet.AppendCustomerAddRq

    ' Set the ICustomerAdd object's field values:
    customer.Name.SetValue("Joey Hamham")

    customer.Phone.SetValue("315-253-2642")

    customer.Email.SetValue("bla@gmail")

    ' The request message set for this example is complete
    ' Open a connection:
    SessionManager.OpenConnection("App", "AddCu")
    ' Begin a session:
    SessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare)

    ' Create a IMsgSetResponse object:
    Dim Resp As IMsgSetResponse

    ' Call DoRequests, passing the IMsgSetRequest object that was populated with a 
    Resp = SessionManager.DoRequests(CustomerSet)

    ' Display the unprocessed QBXML in the response in a message box:
    MsgBox(Resp.ToXMLString)

    ' End the session:
    SessionManager.EndSession()
    ' Close the connection:
    SessionManager.CloseConnection()
    ' Clear the QBSessionManager
    SessionManager = Nothing
End Sub
```